# Indent wrongly after /* */ in CSS with Vim

Tags: css, vim, comments

I have the followings in .vimrc.

```
" tab setting
set noeb vb t_vb=
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
```

When I use `=G` to indent properly in Vim, lines after /*  */ will be commented further.

Before:

```
/*********
#header
*******************/
#header{
    width: 272px;
    height: 82px;
    margin: 0 auto 18px;
}

/************
footer
*****************/
#footer{
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

After:

```
  /*********
  #header
  *******************/
  #header{
    width: 272px;
    height: 82px;
    margin: 0 auto 18px;
  }

  /************
  footer
  *****************/
  #footer{
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

What I am looking for is no 2 spaces after /*  */.

```
/*********
#header
*******************/
#header{
  width: 272px;
  height: 82px;
  margin: 0 auto 18px;
}

/************
footer
*****************/
#footer{
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Can you point out where the problem is? In your example, I see no indentation problems in the "After" block, except that all of it is indented more than what you're after.

Comment: That's the problem for me Mr Lister.

Comment: So is has nothing to do with the /* */?

Comment: I do not think the `'eb'` and `'vb'` settings matter.  What do you have for `:set cindent? indentexpr? smartindent?`?